# Field equations of parametrized field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, klein-gordon-equation

I have problems calculating the field equations of parametrized field theory.

Parametrized field theory is essentially the Klein-Gordon field $\phi$ but, considering the "inertial coordinates" $X^{A}$ as additional dynamical fields.

From here on, we will use the Einstein's summation convention with indices up and down.

Let $X^{A}=(T,X^{a})$ inertial coordinates in the Minkowski spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ with metric $\eta_{AB}$. The starting point is the real scalar field $\phi(X^{A})$. Now the set $X^{A}$ are parametrized by a new
set of arbitrary coordinates $x^{\mu}=(t,x^{b})$ such that for fixed t, the ‘embedding variables’
$X^{A}(t, x^{1}
,\dots,x^{4}$) define a spacelike Cauchy slice of the flat spacetime (https://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:gr-qc/0607068). Now the $X^{A}$ are ‘parameterized’ by $x^{\alpha}$, $X^{A}=X^{A}(x)$

Considering that the lagrangian density of the usual Klein-Gordon field is:
$$\mathcal{L}_{KG}=\dfrac{1}{2}[\eta^{AB}\partial_{A}\phi\partial_{B}\phi-m^{2}\phi^{2}],$$
I calculated the new Lagrangian density, and I obtained the result:

\begin{equation}\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}=\dfrac{1}{2}J\left[\eta^{AB}\dfrac{\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}-m^{2}\phi^{2}\right]\end{equation}

where $\partial_{\alpha}\phi=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$, there is sum over $A, B, \alpha, \beta$ and $J:=\epsilon_{CDEF}\dfrac{\partial X^{C}}{\partial x^{0}}\dfrac{\partial X^{D}}{\partial x^{1}}\dfrac{\partial X^{E}}{\partial x^{2}}\dfrac{\partial X^{F}}{\partial x^{3}}$ is the Jacobi determinant of the $X$ with respect to the $x$.

My first question is; is it valid to consider that

$$\frac{\partial X^{A}}{\partial x^{\mu}}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial X^{A}}}?$$

Because in this case we will have

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{PKG2}=\dfrac{1}{2}J\left[\eta^{AB}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi\partial_{A}x^{\alpha}\partial_{B}x^{\beta}-m^{2}\phi^{2}\right]\end{equation}
and this essentially agrees with what is given in ahttps://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:gr-qc/0607068.

On the other hand, I have problems calculating the field equations of the fields $X^{A}$. The field equations for $X^{A}$ would be given by the Lagrange equations

$$\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}_{PKG}}{\partial X^{G}}-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\left(\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}_{PKG}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}X^{G})}\right)=0,$$

however I have problems calculating the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$.

One of my questions is, should I use the expresion $\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}$ or $\mathcal{L}_{PKG2}$?

I think that $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}}{\partial X^{G}}=0$, because $\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}$ doesn't depend explicitly of $X^{G}$. However, in the case of $\mathcal{L}_{PKG2}$ we have $\partial_{A}x^{\alpha}=\dfrac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial X^{A}}$ and we can calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2 x^{\alpha}}{\partial X^{G}\partial X^{A}}$. I think both Lagrangians must be equivalent, but Honestly I am very confused in this part.

My other question comes when I try to calculate $\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}X^{G})}$. In this case, I need to calculate

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left[\eta^{AB}\dfrac{\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\right].$$

I decomposed this expresion as

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left[\eta^{AB}\dfrac{\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\right]=\eta^{AB}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left(\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\right)+\eta^{AB}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left(\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\right),$$

Using $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left(\dfrac{\partial 
 X^{J}}{\partial y^{\tau}}\right)=\delta_{G}^{J}\delta_{\tau}^{\mu}$, and the quotient rule for derivatives, I obtained for one of the terms that

$$\eta^{AB}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_{\mu}X^{G}\right)}\left(\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\right)=-\eta^{AB}\partial_{\alpha}\phi\partial_{\beta}\phi\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\beta}X^{B}}\left(\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\right)^2 \delta_{\alpha}^{\mu}\delta_{G}^{A}$$

but I clearly have a terrible problem with the indices $\alpha$ and $A$. Who is adding with whom? Even worse, $\left(\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}\dfrac{1}{\partial_{\alpha}X^{A}}$, and this adds even more indices $\alpha$ and $A$. I have tried to fixe it, but I don't know how to rename the indices to avoid the problem.

And, to be honest, I have problems deciding which of the Lagrangians $\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}$ or $\mathcal{L}_{PKG2}$ is correct. I mean, I think both should be equivalent.

I have tried to stablish an analogy with the parametrized non-relativistic particle (PNRP) to try to solve the problems. and in this case, the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{PKG1}$ is the most similar to the Lagrangian of PNRP. And I haven't found any reference with the explicit Lagrange equations of the variables $X^{A}$.